# PG_GETARG_FLOAT4() allways returning 0

Tags: c, postgresql, apache-age

I have written a function for Apache AGE to create a specific kind of graph where the creation of edges is based on a probability, which is one argument of the function. The problem is that, when calling `PG_GETARG_FLOAT4` it always returns `0` instead of the passed floating point number. I'm using GDB to help me debug it and printing `set_prob` shows:

```c
/* --------- Apache AGE Code --------*/
    float4 set_prob;

    /* (more code in between) */

    /* Get the probability for each edge to exist. */
    if (PG_ARGISNULL(2))
    {
        ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                                errmsg("Probability cannot be NULL.")));
    }
    set_prob = PG_GETARG_FLOAT4(2);


/* -------------- GDB -------------- */
p set_prob
0
```

Also, generating a random probability also return `0`.

```c
/* --------- Apache AGE Code --------*/

/* Generate a random float number between 0 and 1. */
random_prob = (float) ((rand() % 100) / 100);

/* -------------- GDB -------------- */

printf "%.2f\n", random_prob
0.00
```

This is how the created function declared and called:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ag_catalog.age_create_erdos_renyi_graph(graph_name name, 
                                                n int, 
                                                p float,
                                                vertex_label_name name = NULL,
                                                edge_label_name name = NULL,
                                                bidirectional bool = true)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE c
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
PARALLEL SAFE
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME';


-- How I'm calling it.
SELECT ag_catalog.age_create_erdos_renyi_graph('test', 5, 0.5, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

What is the proper way to retrieve the float argument and to generate the random number in this case?

Comment: I believe it's returning 0 'cause it's doing an interger division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work for generating a random probability:

```
float random_prob = (float) (rand() % 100) / 100.0;
printf ("%.2f\n", random_prob);
```

I didn't find the function `PG_GETARG_FLOAT4` declaration, but you could use the function `DatumGetFloat4(arg)` to retrieve the float argument, like this:

```
set_prob = DatumGetFloat4(PG_GETARG_DATUM(2));
```

You could also try this:

```
float prob = (float) PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(2);
```

Comment: The macro `PG_GETARG_FLOAT4` is declared at `postgresql-version/src/include/fmgr.h` as : `#define PG_GETARG_FLOAT4(n)  DatumGetFloat4(PG_GETARG_DATUM(n))`. And still does not work :(   I tried passing as an `Name` argument and then casting to `float`, this way did work but it is quite strange to do it like this.

Comment: I think this occur because of a type mismatch with float and float4, probably `PG_GETARG_FLOAT4` doesn't accept the float type. You can try using `float8 set_prob = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(2);`, with this function you can retrieve the float argument correctly

Comment: Yes, `float` is an alias for `double precision`, which is the same as `float8`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using PG_GETARG_FLOAT8 in place of of PG_GETARG_FLOAT4 for the retrieval. Modify  the code code like this:

```
float set_prob;

/* (more code in between) */

/* Get the probability for each edge to exist. */
if (PG_ARGISNULL(2))
{
    ereport(ERROR, (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                    errmsg("Probability cannot be NULL.")));
}
set_prob = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(2);
```

Also, for the random probability, try %f in place of %.2f. The update is as folows:

```
printf("%f\n", random_prob);
```

Hope this will help!!